# How can I improve my code to convert a column of factor into list within a data.frame?

Tags: r

I want to convert a column of factor into lists within a data.frame.
I made it with the code below, but I'm feeling this is not the right way.
How can I improve the code below ?

The data I'm dealing with is a result of association rules.(Using the package: arules) (it's in Japanese)
Here are 3 rows of the column "rules":

> rules
>   {道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,昼間12時間平均旅行速度=20～30km/h,歩道設置率=100%,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし} => {事故類型=車両相互_追突}
>   {道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,昼間12時間平均旅行速度=20～30km/h,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし} => {事故類型=車両相互_追突}
>   {道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,歩道設置率=100%,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし,代表沿道状況=人口集中地区（商業地域を除く）} => {事故類型=車両相互_追突}

And str(data)

> 'data.frame': 50 obs. of  5 variables:
>    $ rules     : Factor w/ 50 levels "{道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし,指定最高速度=50} => {事故類型=車両相互_追突}",..: 9 8 35 38 10 31 11 25 3 7 ...
>    $ support   : Factor w/ 48 levels "0.050295052",..: 5 14 5 10 24 1 30 13 15 18 ...
>    $ confidence: Factor w/ 50 levels "0.555131629",..: 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 ...
>    $ lift      : Factor w/ 50 levels "1.894879112",..: 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 ...
>    $ count     : Factor w/ 48 levels "1013","1250",..: 9 18 9 14 28 5 34 17 19 22 ...

```r
# convert factor to character
data %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) -> data

# delete the RHS in rules(the part after '=>' )
data$rules <- strsplit(data$rules, " =>")
i = 1
for (i in 1:length(data$rules)) {
  data$rules[[i]] <- data$rules[[i]][[-2]]
}

# delete "{" and "}"
data$rules <- as.character(data$rules)
data$rules <- strsplit(data$rules, "[{]")
i = 1
for (i in 1:length(data$rules)) {
  data$rules[[i]] <- data$rules[[i]][[-1]]
}

data$rules <- as.character(data$rules)
data$rules <- strsplit(data$rules, "[}]")

# split character to list (:length(data$rules[[1]] -> 4))
data$rules <- as.character(data$rules)
data$rules <- strsplit(data$rules, ",")
```

The output should be like this:

```r
[[1]]
[1] "道路構造=交差点_交差点付近"        "昼間12時間平均旅行速度=20～30km/h" "歩道設置率=100%"                   "バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし"   

[[2]]
[1] "道路構造=交差点_交差点付近"        "昼間12時間平均旅行速度=20～30km/h" "バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし"   

[[3]]
[1] "道路構造=交差点_交差点付近"                  "歩道設置率=100%"                             "バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし"             
[4] "代表沿道状況=人口集中地区（商業地域を除く）"
```

My code did work, however, I just feel it's not beautiful, or efficient.
So could you improve it. Or, the right way to do this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
out <- data %>% 
         mutate(rules = trimws(str_extract(rules, "(?<=\\{)[^}]+")))
out$rules
#[1] "道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,昼間12時間平均旅行速度=20～30km/h,歩道設置率=100%,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし"          
#[2] "道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,昼間12時間平均旅行速度=20～30km/h,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし"                          
#[3] "道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,歩道設置率=100%,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし,代表沿道状況=人口集中地区（商業地域を除く）"
```

If we want to split the 'rules' by `,` and create a `list` column

```
out$rules <- str_split(out$rules, ",")
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(rules = c("{道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,昼間12時間平均旅行速度=20～30km/h,歩道設置率=100%,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし} => {事故類型=車両相互_追突}", 
"{道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,昼間12時間平均旅行速度=20～30km/h,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし} => {事故類型=車両相互_追突}", 
"{道路構造=交差点_交差点付近,歩道設置率=100%,バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし,代表沿道状況=人口集中地区（商業地域を除く）} => {事故類型=車両相互_追突}"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Very efficient!  It does work. This really confuses me, how should I learn, or exercise, so that I can deal with data as beautifully as you ?

Comment: sorry, I didn't make my question clear, the final result I want is like this:  [1] "道路構造=交差点_交差点付近"        "昼間12時間平均旅行速度=20～30km/h" "歩道設置率=100%"                   "バス優先.専用レーンの有無=なし"   .  For each row of column "rules", converted into list.

Comment: @guttentag_liu  If you want as a list, then  use `out$rules <- as.list(out$rules)`

Comment: I think maybe ```r  out$rules <- strsplit(out$rules, ",")  ```  is right, so that I can split each part between the "," .

Comment: Really thank you. Could I bother you a little more. What should I exercise or learn to get my lines of code simple and efficient as you do ?

Comment: @guttentag_liu An option would be to read the vignettes of tidyversee